# Understanding enumset for enumerators

Tags: java, methods, enums, enumset, method-declaration

As far as I understood it would be much easier and clearler to use `EnumSet` and that the `Set` was specifically designed for using with Enumerators. My question is whether we should consider to use the `EnumSet` every time we need to maintain some collection of enumerators. For instance, I have he following enum:

```
public enum ReportColumns{
    ID,
    NAME,
    CURRENCY
    //It may contain much more enumerators than I mentioned here

    public int getMaintenanceValue(){ 
        //impl
    }
}
```

And I need to use some collection ofthe enum in the method:

```
public void persist(Collection<ReportColumns> cols){
    List<Integer> ints = new LinkedList<>();
    for(ReportColumn c: cols){
        ints.add(c.getMaintenanceValue());
    }
    //do some persistance-related operations
}
```

so, if I don't care about if the collection is ordered or not should I use `EnumSet<E>` every time to improve performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, whenever you **create** a collection of enums and don't care about their order, you should create an `EnumSet`. As you mentioned, it would give you a slight increase in performance (in fact, most static code analysis tools I know actually warn about not using it).

For a method **declaration** though, I wouldn't. As another rule of thumb, methods should use the "highest" type possible that still makes sense. The public contract of this method should be "give me a bunch of enums, and I'll persist them". The method shouldn't care what collection is passed, so it makes no sense forcing the parameter type to be an `EnumSet`. If the concrete type you pass is indeed an `EnumSet` you'll get all the performance benefits anyway.